# Can Spark automatically detect nondeterministic results and adjust failure recovery accordingly?

Tags: apache-spark

If nondeterministic code runs on Spark, this can cause a problem when recovery from failure of a node is necessary, because the new output may not be exactly the same as the old output. My interpretation is that the entire job might need to be rerun in this case, because otherwise the output data could be inconsistent with itself (as different data was produced at different times). At the very least any nodes that are downstream from the recovered node would probably need to be restarted from scratch, because they have processed data that may now change. That's my understanding of the situation anyway, please correct me if I am wrong.

My question is whether Spark can somehow automatically detect if code is nondeterministic (for example by comparing the old output to the new output) and adjust the failure recovery accordingly. If this were possible it would relieve application developers of the requirement to write nondeterministic code, which might sometimes be challenging and in any case this requirement can easily be forgotten.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the terms you are using. There are no "downstream nodes" in Spark. Are you talking about stages?

Comment: What I mean is that in Spark data is partitioned and at each stage it's processed on a variety of different nodes i.e. servers. The output from one server will be sent to another server (thus I say it is "downstream") to perform a different operation which relies on the data processed by the first server. Often this will be streaming so that the second server doesn't need to wait for the first to fully complete before running.

Comment: In this case if the first server then fails and is restarted, there's a question of what to do to the second server. If the operation being performed on the first server is deterministic, the operation on the second server doesn't necessarily need to be restarted (it can ignore the output it has already seen). But if the first server's operation is nondeterministic, it will be best to restart the operation on the second server.

Comment: Sorry about terminology, I only know a little bit about Spark so far but I've been reading about it in a CS book that may use nonstandard terms.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the non-deterministic output you are talking about?

Comment: Code is not non determinstic, rather the outcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772790/spark-efficiency-of-dataframe-checkpoint-vs-explicitly-writing-to-disk  This is a good post.

Comment: An example of nondeterministic output would be if code iterates over the keys of a dictionary (outputting the value each time), because in most programming languages the keys are not guaranteed to be provided in a particular order.

Comment: @thebluephantom I disagree, it's the code that is deterministic or not, not the output. You could have a piece of nondeterministic code that generates the same output the first two times we run it, but we still wouldn't say that the output was deterministic because we could get a different result when we run it the third time. You have to look at the properties of the code: it is deterministic if it has properties such that it will always generate the same output. Anyway this is sort of tangential to my question.

Comment: we agree to disagree i think

Answer (score 0):

No. Spark will not be able to handle non deterministic code in case of failures. The fundamental data structure of Spark, RDD is not only immutable but it
should also be determinstic function of it's input. This is necessary otherwise Spark framework will not be able to recompute the partial RDD (partition) in case of
failure. If the recomputed partition is not deterministic then it had to re-run the transformation again on full RDDs in lineage. I don't think that Spark is a right
framework for non-deterministic code.

If Spark has to be used for such use case, application developer has to take care of keeping the output consistent by writing code carefully. It can be done by using RDD only (no datframe or dataset) and persisting output after every transformation executing non-determinstic code. If performance is the concern, then the intermediate RDDs can be persisted on Alluxio.

A long term approach would be to open a feature request in apache spark jira. But I am not too positive about the acceptance of feature. A little hint in syntax to know wether code is deterministic or not and framework can switch to recover RDD partially or fully.

Comment: You say: "This is necessary otherwise Spark framework will not be able to recompute the partial RDD (partition) in case of failure. If the recomputed partition is not deterministic then it had to re-run the transformation again on full RDDs in lineage." It seems like you are saying that Spark knows whether it is deterministic or not, so it makes a decision about whether to recompute partial or full accordingly. Does it know automatically? Or does the application developer have to manually "mark" code as deterministic or nondeterministic?

Comment: Spark expects that code is deterministic and it does not recompute the full rdd as of now. This is the reason I asked to open a new feature request at the end of my answer.

Comment: Look, I consider myself as having a few clues, but there are some true experts on SO that have not yet responded to this question. That tells me something. The notion of caching is missed.

Answer (score 0):

Non-deterministic results are not detected and accounted for in failure recovery (at least in spark 2.4.1, which I'm using).

I have encountered issues with this a few times on spark. For example, let's say I use a window function:
`first_value(field_1) over (partition by field_2 order by field_3)`

If field_3 is not unique, the result is non-deterministic and can differ each time that function is run. If a spark executor dies and restarts while calculating this window function, you can actually end up with two different first_value results output for the same field_2 partition.