# Read dataframe with same partitioner it was persisted to HDFS

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, bucket, checkpoint

I have a generic spark 2.3 job that does many transformations and joins and produces a huge dag.
That is having a big impact on driver side as dag becomes very complex.

In order to release pressure on the driver I've though on checkpointing some intermediate dataframes to cut the dag, but I've noticed that dataframe.checkpoint is using rdds underneath and it spends many time serializing and deserializing the dataframe.

According to this [Spark: efficiency of dataframe checkpoint vs. explicitly writing to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772790/spark-efficiency-of-dataframe-checkpoint-vs-explicitly-writing-to-disk) and my experience, writing the dataframe as parquet and reading it back is faster than checkpointing, but it has a disadvantage. Dataframe loses the partitioner.

Is there any way of writing and reading the dataframe and keep the partitioner? I've though in using buckets when writing the dataframe, so that when the dataframe is read back it knows the data partitioning.
Problem is, how can I know the columns that the dataframe has as partitioner?
Spark job I'm running is kind of generic, so I can't hardcode the columns

Thanks

Comment: So what do you mean with release pressure on the driver?

Comment: When the dag is very big, it seems that the driver is spending too much time analyzing and optimizing the execution plan. While this is happening executors are doing nothing. In one of the cases I've notice that it can stay like that for 20 minutes before executors have some job to do, and if I persist and read back some intermediate dataframes to cut the dag that "executors not doing anything" time is gone

Comment: I have noted such things as well but find little discussion on it.

Comment: The thing is that while I've noticed a huge performance improvement, I would like to go a little bit further and see if partitioner can be kept somehow to avoid extra shuffles (sometimes next transformation is a join with another table that has the same partitioner)

Comment: It's an area I researched a while ago, but I would like to understand it better the delay myself. It's an odd story, so let us see who answers. In Spark 3 things are also a little different.